A probabilistic proof of Lipschitz function can be written as the integral of a measurable function
Background:
Fix a Lipschitz function $f: [ 0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.We also let $X$ be a random variable with values in $[0,1)$,which is uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$.For every integer $n\geq0$, we set $$X_n=2^{-n}\lfloor2^nX\rfloor\quad\mathrm{and}\quad Z_n=2^n(f(X_n+2^{-n})-f(X_n))$$and we let $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_0,..,X_n)$be the canonical filtration of the process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$.

Question:Compute $\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$ for any bounded Borel function $h:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.Infer
that $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a bounded martingale with respect
to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$.

Note: It is an exercise in my textbook.
I was able to prove a previous result:$\sigma(X_0,X_1,\ldots)=\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_n),\forall n\ge 0$.
My try:Denote $I_{n+1}$ as follows: $$I_{n+1}:=\{[2^{n+1}X]=2[2^nX]\},I_{n+1}^c=\{[2^{n+1}X]=2[2^nX]+1\}$$In other words $I_{n+1}=\{X_{n+1}=X_n\},I_{n+1}^c=\{X_{n+1}=X_n+2^{-n-1}\}$
For any $A\in \mathcal F_n$,we compute:$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[h(X_{n+1})1_A]&=\mathbb E[h(X_{n+1})1_{I_{n+1}}1_A+h(X_{n+1})1_{I^c_{n+1}}1_A]\\&=\mathbb E[\big(h(X_n)1_{I_{n+1}}+h(X_n+2^{-n-1})1_{I^c_{n+1}}\big)1_A]
\end{align}$$But it seems not work,since $1_{I_{n+1}}$ is still $\sigma(X_{n+1})-$measurable. And if we use the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$ to write things more precisely we get $$\begin{align}&
\mathbb E[\big(h(X_n)1_{I_{n+1}}+h(X_n+2^{-n-1})1_{I^c_{n+1}}\big)1_A]\\&=\int_0^1\big(h([2^{-n}[2^nx])1_{\{[2^{n+1}x]=2[2^nx]\}}+h([2^{-n}[2^nx]+2^{-n-1})1_{\{[2^{n+1}x]=2[2^nx]+1\}}\big)1_A\mathrm{dx}
\end{align}$$But it seems to be a messy integral and I am stuck here.
See a more general result here,but I still find it hard to get $\mathbb E[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal F_n]$
Any help would be appreciated.

Without loss of generality, suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)=([0,1),\mathscr{B}[0,1),\lambda)$ and set $X(\omega)=\omega$. We have
$$X^n(\omega)=\sum_{0\leq k< 2^n}(k2^{-n})\mathbf{1}_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}(\omega)$$
So that $\sigma(X^n)=\sigma(\{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}),0\leq k < 2^n\})$. So $A \in \sigma(X^n)$ is some finite disjoint union of sets of the form $[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$. For the conditional expectation, we may then just argue over the generating family $\{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}),0\leq k < 2^n\}$. We want some $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable function, that, if integrated over $[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$ yields the same integral of $h(X^{n+1})$. We have
$$\begin{aligned}
&E[\mathbf{1}_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}h(X^{n+1})]\\
&=h((2k)2^{-(n+1)})\lambda([(2k)2^{-(n+1)},(2k+1)2^{-(n+1)}))\\
&+h((2k+1)2^{-(n+1)})\lambda([(2k+1)2^{-(n+1)},(2k+2)2^{-(n+1)}))\\
&=(h((2k)2^{-(n+1)})+h((2k+1)2^{-(n+1)}))2^{-(n+1)}\\
&=(h(k2^{-n})+h(k2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)}))2^{-(n+1)}
\end{aligned}$$
But then the function
$$W^{n,h}:=\frac{h(X^n)+h(X^n+2^{-(n+1)})}{2}$$
Satisfies our requirement:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&E[\mathbf{1}_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}W^{n,h}]\\
&=\frac{h(k2^{-n})+h(k2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)})}{2}\lambda([k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}))\\
&=\frac{h(k2^{-n})+h(k2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)})}{2}2^{-n}\\
&=(h(k2^{-n})+h(k2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)}))2^{-(n+1)}
\end{aligned}$$
We now check that $Z^n$ is a martingale:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&E[Z^{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n]\\
&=E[2^{n+1}(f(X^{n+1}+2^{-(n+1)})-f(X^{n+1}))|\mathscr{F}_n]\\
&=\frac{2^{n+1}(f(X^{n}+2^{-(n+1)})-f(X^{n}))+2^{n+1}(f(X^{n}+2^{-(n+1)}+2^{-(n+1)})-f(X^{n}+2^{-(n+1)}))}{2}\\
&=2^n(f(X^n+2^{-n})-f(X_n))\\
&=Z^n
\end{aligned}$$

Thanks for your answer!I think the main subtlety lies in the proof is $2^{-n}[2^nx]=k2^{-n}$ for some $k$,and therefore $\sigma(2^{-n}[2^nX])=\sigma({k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}.0\leq k<2^n})$.Am I right?

@QoAo indeed the 'shape' of the sequence of functions is a relevant argument here
